# MySQL delete row if there is no foreign constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One called `peoples` another called `addresses`. The `peoples` table has a foreign constraint on the `address` table (`peoples.address_id = addresses.address_id`) Multiple people may have the same address. There is a unique constraint on the `address` column on the `addresses` table

I came across a situation where I have to delete a person from the `peoples` table and the associated address on the on the `addresses` table IF AND ONLY IF there is no other record in the `peoples` table who have the same address.

How can I go about doing this in MySQL?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, tbh (IF AND ONLY IF)... do you mean that an address must have at least 2 people associated with it?  BTW: People will have multiple addresses, so normalizing this structure will help in the long run.

Comment: This isn't a homework question. This isn't even my actual problem, but a sample problem I've made up with fake tables and constraints to figure out how I can delete a row in a table if there are no rows in another table that uses that row as a foreign constraint.

Comment: Not sure if I would get yelled at for this solution, so I'll just post it as a comment....couldn't you just try and delete the address? If you have your constraints set up, it should yell at you if there is another table still referencing that row, so it shouldn't delete it. That way it's only one trip to the server. Only downside I see is that you're relying on an error from the database...

Comment: You didn't answer my more important question: do you mean that an address must have at least 2 people associated with it?

Comment: @Travesty3 I like that idea but I don't want to display errors to my users.

Comment: @Xecure: You wouldn't display the error. Depending on how you're doing your query (hopefully PDO), you would just execute the query and check for an error. If it's the error you were expecting, continue without displaying the error. A MySQL error shouldn't halt PHP execution unless you tell it to. In any case, I think my answer below is better anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be more performant than doing a subquery:

```
DELETE
    addresses
FROM
    addresses
    LEFT JOIN peoples
        ON addresses.address_id = peoples.address_id
WHERE
    peoples.address_id IS NULL
```

It should delete all addresses that aren't referenced in the `peoples` table. If you want to only delete the specific address in question, add something to the `WHERE` clause like `AND addresses.address_id = '<address_id>'`.

## [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe93ff/1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` clause like below

```
DELETE FROM addresses 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM peoples WHERE peoples.address_id=addresses.address_id)
```

The cons against this is it will be pretty slow as it will re-run the query for every address row that exists. Otherwise it should solve the problem.

Delete the person first. Then this query deletes if the address has no people